How to trigger a replacement action by inputting a symbol in vscode?
For example, in perl code $obj->method(), I want to automatically replace $obj. with $obj->
I tried to use snippets to achieve this:
...
"Object->": {
  "prefix": ".",
  "body": [
    "->$0"
  ],
  "description": ". convert to ->"
}


But when inputting . and TAB key, it cannot be triggered effectively.
What's the problem?
Please help, thank you very much.

Try adding space/TAB character after the dot in prefix - "prefix": ".⇥", or "prefix": ". ",

The problem is using the special character . as the prefix, see User Snippets don't show up after dot.

Today, the snippet logic is not even asked when a trigger character,
like dot, is being hit. The reason for not asking every provider on
trigger characters that they are meant to be used for things like
member completion. Getting unrelated suggestions after e.g. console.
might confuse folks.

So the issue has been marked as a Feature Request and closed.
Putting any character after the . in the prefix works and the snippet suggestion will be automatically opened. For example:
"Object->": {
  "prefix": ".a",     // whatever you want after the .
  "body": [
    "->$0"
  ],
  "description": ". convert to ->"
}

Or, you can leave it at "prefix": ".", and manually trigger the snippet completions with Ctrl+Space.
And see https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/75402 but it doesn't seem like it is really fixed.
Probably related: Snippets disappear with . key
